# Matlibplot table stretching and moving

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, stretch

Im trying to adjust this table so that it will take up the entire window, but no combination of the top, bottom left and right sliders will allow me to do it, all they do is shrink the grid while translating it.

Is there a way to stretch this vertically?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from random import randint

def colour(value):
    r,g,b = 0,0,0
    if value < 1:
        r = 1
        g = 1*value
    if value > 1:
        r = 1 - 1*(value-1)
        g = 1
    if value == 1:
        r = 1
        g = 1
    if value > 2:
        b = 1
    colour  =  (r,g,b)

    return colour

ncols, nrows = 7,8
row= [[]]*nrows
for i in range(nrows):
    row[i] = i*3

print(row)
col = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sat', 'Sun']
list = []
text = ['','','','','','','']

for a in range(nrows):
     list.append(text)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
image = ax.table(cellText=list, colLabels = col, rowLabels=row)
for j in range(ncols):
    for i in range(nrows):
        print(i,j)
        value = randint(0,200)
        value = value / 100       
        image._cells[(i+1,j)].set_facecolor(colour(value))

figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the table *below* the axes. It seems you would rather like to create it *within* the axes,

```
table = ax.table(..., loc="center")
```

To then adjust the vertical span, you may set the scale, e.g. to double the size in y direction:

```
table.scale(1,2)
```

The result would then look like

[image]

Alternatively, specify the bounding box of the table with respect to the axes. To fill the complete axes,

```
table = ax.table(..., bbox=[0,0,1,1])
```

Then calling `fig.tight_layout()` adjusts the margins as usual.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the zoom tool, and select a region wider than it is tall (e.g., the top left corner to the bottom right) to change the aspect ratio. You may also be able to adjust the `figsize` to get a better aspect ratio.